# why does float number minus operation out wrong result?

Tags: javascript

```
0.03-0.0218 = 0.008199999999999999
```

why is it that?
I am using javascript.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is approximative.
Either use a library that does deal with it or accept the small error.

Comment: Thanks but there seems to be no answer how to get right result,
I need 0.0082.
They said about the reason, but now I need real solution.

Comment: May be worth exploring [Big.JS](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/)